# is there a way to cache youtube videos based on url?

Tags: caching, youtube, browser-cache, offline-caching, http-caching

I am curious to know about youtube video caching.

After through study of URLs which are actually responsible for video content, I observed that they are too dynamic in nature and it is close to impossible to cache them based on URL.

> ex url - https://r1---sn-o3o-cvhe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?fexp=9405969%2C9408215%2C9416126%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9422781%2C9423660%2C9423662%2C9424135%2C9426943%2C9427036%2C9427902%2C9428399%2C9429315%2C9429352%2C9429923%2C9431261&itag=247&clen=27606044&keepalive=yes&key=yt6&upn=h76l3Me-Z5U&sver=3&dur=142.000&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=13781250&pcm2cms=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&lmt=1455539528057700&gir=yes&expire=1459450714&gcr=in&mv=m&id=o-ACb0u5vw3dhRbBs7zcsNK93Ni7RA2Wazh8dBCZvFZLAw&ms=au&source=youtube&mm=31&mn=sn-o3o-cvhe&pl=24&mt=1459428863&ip=103.21.125.77&mime=video%2Fwebm&requiressl=yes&cpn=chXTzESYb8N9EdnF&alr=yes&ratebypass=yes&signature=4746B746901E60BEC12FDC9C6EA5357BF9AF254E.2BD3F3CF6C77106C73211F2231D91DF3AE340B68&c=WEB&cver=1.20160329&range=13804074-15885122&rn=28&rbuf=57430

URL has many query string parameters which do not even follow order and some varying parameters like signature, range etc.

Do they intentionally generate such URLs ?

Is there any other way of caching youtube videos which can detect same video even with different URL ?